# I have a CLOB field with XML data and we need to convert the XML to columns with value concatenation

Tags: oracle

I have a CLOB field with XML data and we need to convert the XML to columns with value concatenation

I require the following output, but unfortunately I could not find any help anywhere.

```
Fld 1        fld2        fld3
Name1        Name2      Addressline$Addressline 2$Addressline 3£Addressline 4$Addressline 5$Addressline 6
```

Means the values in "m" should be concatenated with $ and both "m" should be separated with £

This is my code:

```
    <row> 
<c1>Name1></c1> 
<c2>Name2</c2> 
<c6>Addressline</c6> 
<c6 m=1 s=2>Addressline 2 </c6>
<c6 m=1 s=1>Addressline 3 </c6>
<c6 m=2 s=1>Addressline 4</c6> 
<c6 m=2 s=2>Addressline 5</c6>
<c6 m=2 s=3>Addressline 6</c6>
   </row>
```

Comment: Kindly find the below example code

<row>
<c1>Name1></c1>
<c2>Name2</c2>
<c6>Addressline</c6>
<c6 m=1 s=2>Addressline 2 </c6>
<c6 m=1 s=1>Addressline 3 </c6>
 
<c6 m=2 s=1>Addressline 4</c6>
<c6 m=2 s=2>Addressline 5</c6>
<c6 m=2 s=3>Addressline 6</c6>
</row>.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please add your code when you post in the future, and if you forget to add it, you can edit your question.